# Is there an updated version of "Improving .NET Application Performance and Scalability"?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, scalability

I'm looking for an updated version of this article: [Improving .NET Application Performance and Scalability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998530).

The message on this page states:

*Retired Content*

*This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained. It is provided as a courtesy for individuals who are still using these technologies. This page may contain URLs that were valid when originally published, but now link to sites or pages that no longer exist.*

I'm looking for either an update of this article or a collection of articles with the same emphasis.

A (recent) book on .NET performance and scalability is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google check and wording of that statement indicates no, but perhaps the blog of one of the authors may help?  Esp. his "Performance" tag?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/tags/performance/

Comment: It appears that no, there is no update that deals specifically with performance.  
This is the closest answer.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Application Architecture Guide (From the Microsoft Patterns and Practices Team)

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Application-Architecture-Patterns-Practices/dp/073562710X/ref=pd_sim_b_8

That's the one you're are looking for.

Excellent book ... happy reading :-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that an updated article exists. However, I wouldn't let the retired content disclaimer discourage you from reading the article and heeding it's advice. While some information may be outdated and some links might be invalid, there is probably a lot of useful information that still applies.

Technology will always continue to improve, but the basics of good programming rarely change.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few that I've looked at in the past.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/pdc2008/TL24

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/10ASPNetPerformance.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some of the same information, particularly in regard to testing, can be found in the 2007 J.D. Meier series, "[Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx)" series.

The patterns & practices Application Architecture Guide 2.02 also mentioned above from October 2009 contains some of the architectural information.

Enterprise and cloud based development guides are gathered [here](http://pnp.azurewebsites.net/en-us/projects.htm).  In particular the 2013, 273 page  Book Download: Data Access for Highly-Scalable Solutions: Using SQL, NoSQL, and Polyglot Persistence5 has some very useful information.

And the 2012, Developing Multi-tenant Applications for the Cloud, 3rd Edition - Book Download

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into Iqbal Khan's articles on improving .net application's performance and scalability using distributed caching solutions like [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714590.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942840.aspx